# Combine Microsoft nuget with lower dotnet core version

Tags: .net-core

I have a dotnet core 2.1 lts docker image and I need to have a timestamp in the log. The [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/3.0.0-preview4.19216.2) preview for dotnet core 3.0 has this feature. Of course this package will not have long term support.

Can I combine a nuget package, which share the version of dotnet core, with a lower version of the dotnet core framework or does that result into in unsupported setup?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your applications uses, so I need to write a somewhat generic answer.

The package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging targets netstandard 2.0, which means it will work on dotnet core 2.1

This issue you will have, is that it will force the dependencies it uses to upgrade too:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 3.0.0-preview4.19216.2)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 3.0.0-preview4.19216.2)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0-preview4.19216.2)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options (>= 3.0.0-preview4.19216.2)
```

And those have dependencies too... in the end it might upgrade quite a lot of your project dependencies with packages which are in preview. (thus not supported)

I would not advice you to do this, but in the end it simply depends on what functionality you are using in your application. If only your code depends on the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging functionality you should be okay, although currently not supported. As soon as you use other packages which use one of the upgrade Microsoft.Extensions package the major version change should tell you that this might cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. You wrote "thus not supported". Did you mean because it is preview (and will this when core 3.0 becomes stable in September) or because they are a lot?